# Trying to Use .Htaccess to 301 redirect all pages but one. However The One Page Exception Rule is Not Working

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, fat-free-framework

I have been trying to redirect all of my website's pages to a new website but would like to rule out one single page as an exception. This is the code I am using:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/en/planning/$
RewriteRule .* https://www.target.example/ [R=301,L]
```

As you can see, I am trying redirect all pages to a new domain but leave the `/en/planning/` page intact. However, when I use the code above, all pages were redirected without an exception. From the server, I found out that `/en/planning` directory does not really exist. The template to the page however, exists in a different directory.

They are here > `/home/indo/src-20220316-200538/apps/front/templates/planning/views/planning-view.html`.

The header & footer of the page was built in a different directory.

Meanwhile the public_html of the website lies on `/home/indo/www/`
In this directory, there is a shortcut to the original location that is named "front". Here is a screenshot from WinSCP:

[image: Here is the screenshot]

So, based on this, what is the best way to make `/en/planning/` as an exception? the website I am trying to redirect is `http://source.example/` to `https://www.target.example/`. In addition, the website is running with Fat-Free Framework.

I have been stuck here for weeks and this is frustating.

Comment: This should work fine, there is no immediately apparent reason why it shouldn't. Is this the whole content of your .htaccess, or is there more?

Comment: Hi CBroe, yes this is the only content in my .htaccess and there is nothing more to it.

Comment: If that's the _only_ content in your `.htaccess` file then how is the URL `/en/planning/` expected to be routed through your framework? Maybe this is the wrong `.htaccess` file or there are directives in the server config?

Comment: Im pretty sure im doing it in the right file though. The .htaccess I modified is under the /www/ directory. As to the directives in the server config, im not sure im catching what you meant by that.

Comment: Presumably then you don't have access to the server config?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/en/planning/$
> RewriteRule .* https://www.target.example/ [R=301,L]
> ```

You no doubt have other directives (a front-controller pattern) that rewrites URLs of the form `/en/planning/` to the front-controller, which performs the underlying routing. Your front-controller might be `index.php`, or something else.

The "problem" here is that when the request is rewritten to the front-controller, the `REQUEST_URI` server variable is no longer `/en/planning/`, but is updated to `/index.php` (or whatever the front-controller is) and the redirect occurs, since the negated *condition* is now successful. The rewrite engine makes multiple passes, the undesirable redirect is likely occurring on the second pass (the exception is successful initially).

You need to ensure that the you only check the originally requested URL and not the rewritten URL.

However, you also likely need to make an exception for any static resources (images, CSS, JS, etc) that are used by this page, otherwise these would also be redirected.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/en/planning/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ https://www.target.example/ [R=301,L]
```

The check against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable ensures that we only test the initial request from the client and not the rewritten request by Apache.

The additional check against `REQUEST_FILENAME` ensures that the requested URL does not map to an actual file (a static resource). However, the obvious downside of this is that static resources (for other pages) are not redirected.

You also need to make sure the browser cache is cleared, since the erroneous 301 (*permanent*) redirect will have been cached by the browser. Test first with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues.

I would add, however, that a many-to-one redirect to the homepage, as you are implementing here is generally bad for SEO since search engines (particularly Google) will see this as a soft-404 and not honour the redirect, ultimately dropping the pages from the search results.

Comment: Hi, this code you gave does not work.
However it is true that there is a controller file, I just couldnt find the line that defines the /en/planning/.
FYI, The site is using Fat-Free Framework

Comment: @VanbelManik What do you mean exactly, by "not work"? Is this URL still being redirected? No redirect? Malformed redirect? An error of some kind? Have you made sure your browser cache is cleared? (301 - permanent - redirects are cached persistently by the browser

Comment: Sorry I did not clarify the "not working" detail. I tried to put the code you wrote above, however when I access the /en/planning/, the server returns a 404 not found. It is not redirected indeed though.

Comment: @VanbelManik If you are getting a 404 (and no redirect) then it arguably suggests the code above "is working", but the request is not being routed through your framework (a different problem). If you remove this code completely does a request for `/en/planning/` "work"? If you are running Apache and this is the only code in your `.htaccess` file (as suggested in comments below your question) then how are requests being routed through your framework? You need a [front-controller pattern as suggested in the docs](https://www.fatfreeframework.com/3.8/routing-engine#SampleApacheConfiguration)